# vim red highlight $( )

Tags: bash, vim, ubuntu, sh

I was writing a script when I decided to move the functions to a lib file, but when I open the lib file all the `$(` and the consecutive `)` are red highlighted, here are some examples of the script

```
TAB="$(printf '\t')"
percent=$(echo "scale=2; $number/$total*100" | bc | sed -e 's/\.[[:digit:]]*//g')
if [[ -z $(grep $site/post $max_lim) ]];then
```

The filetype is conf but I've set it as sh syntax in .vimrc

Any idea of what is happenning?

Thank you

---

Edit: Thanks for the quick answers, I found that this line makes vim match the files with the extension specified behind the `*` with the syntax sh

```
au BufReadPost * set syntax=sh
```

I've also thought that using shebang in the libraries was not allowed, but is a nice solution

Anyway using `g:is_bash` in .vimrc returns an error of pattern not found

So what I would like to do is as I only write in bash, to vim recognize any file without extension as bash

Comment: highlight you meant color in red? or color in white and bg=red?

Comment: For now, you can `:set ft=sh`, but you might want to post the part of your ~/.vimrc that you think is setting the filetype and the filename so we actually know what is going on. You can always add this to the end of your file too: `# vim: set ft=sh`.

Comment: As an aside, you can you `TAB=$'\t'` to specify a literal tab character in `bash`.

Comment: Just a note, for me the red highlight turned out to be matches to a search, `:noh` fixed that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The syntax file for `sh` actually handles several different kinds of shell syntax: `bash`, `ksh`, and plain old `sh`. Since your conf file isn't recognized as `bash` or `ksh`, it falls back to `sh`. `$(...)` isn't a valid construct in `sh`, so it is highlighted as an error.

To fix this, you can make sure "g:is_bash" is set for the file, so that the `sh` syntax script will know your file should be highlighted as `bash` code. Please edit your question to include what you added to your `.vimrc` to make the file use `sh` syntax highlighting. This will make it easier to suggest the correct way of setting "g:is_bash".

UPDATE: As Alok commented, you should be able to add the following to the file

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to let `vim` know the correct syntax highlighting to use as well.

Comment: It also seems to work if the "shebang line" in the script file says it's a bash script.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that, since it sounds like the file is only sourced and not executed on its own. That's definitely the easiest fix, though.

Comment: Documentation is at [`:h ft-sh-syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#ft-sh-syntax).

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I wanted to preserve `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang line because not every system has `/bin/bash` available.

Whereas the original Bourne shell may have not supported the `$(...)` syntax, most `sh` shells nowadays are POSIX-compliant, and [the POSIX spec supports this syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). For example,

- On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is `/bin/dash`.
- On MacOS, `/bin/sh` is `/bin/bash`.
- On Alpine, `/bin/sh` is `/bin/ash`.

All of which satisfy the POSIX spec. Traditionally, if we'd like to write portable Shell, we should leave the shebang line as `#!/bin/sh`. We shouldn't change it to `#!/bin/bash` just for syntax highlighting if we're not going to use any Bashisms.

Okay, but what about the erroneous red highlighting? The problem is with Vim interpreting `#!/bin/sh` as a reference to [the original Bourne shell from 1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) with no support for `$(...)`. Maybe this is a testament to Vim's backwards compatibility, or maybe not enough people care. Here's a [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1147) describing the same behavior.

In any case, the best solution for me was to set `let g:is_posix = 1` in my config. Interestingly, if you look through Vim's runtime files, it's equivalent to setting [`let g:is_kornshell = 1`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1d9215b9aaa120b9d78fee49488556f73007ce78/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L49-L51). Further down in the same file when it's time to setup the syntax highlighting, there's [some more commentary](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1d9215b9aaa120b9d78fee49488556f73007ce78/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L304-L309) about it:

```
" $() and $(()): {{{1
" $(..) is not supported by sh (Bourne shell).  However, apparently
" some systems (HP?) have as their /bin/sh a (link to) Korn shell
" (ie. Posix compliant shell).  /bin/ksh should work for those
" systems too, however, so the following syntax will flag $(..) as
" an Error under /bin/sh.  By consensus of vimdev'ers!
```

---

A brief interesting history on how the Bourne shell was bourne, bourne again as `bash` as a substitute for `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu, and eventually replaced in favor of `dash` can be found at https://askubuntu.com/a/976504.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for sure. The other one doesn't answer the question at all.